# How to Add Secondary Tiles In Application

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I have the need to have 8 Secondary Live Tiles in my application. I was wondering what the best way to go about doing this would be. I would like to have each tile in a horizontal StackPanel, so I can have text to the right side of the tile as well. Currently my implementation (not using live tiles) looks like this

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="105" Width="432" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Tap="stk1_Tap">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="99" Height="99" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
                        <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,-7,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="Line One" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="line two" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
```

and I have 8 of the above stacked on top of each other. I would like to make what is currently the Border into a LiveTile. I have not seen of a way to do this in XAML. If I was to do this in code behind, what would be the best way to go? Any advice, tips, or input would be greatly appreciated? Any other suggestions?